# UITest cases to handle with location services alert

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am writing UI test cases for my project.

My project flow is as below:

- Login Screen. User enters credentials and press login.
- Home Screen. There is location requirement so system as for user's permission. I allow it.
- Logout.

So when I do fresh install of application this flow is recorded in test case and works if I perform on new fresh build.

But problem is when I test on old build there is no alert for location permission and the test's gets fail. **How can I handle this cases or ask user for permission every time when I run tests?**

For resetting credentials of user I am passing launchArguments to `XCUIApplication()` and handle in AppDelegate.

I have implemented code **let me know if its correct way**:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Allow “APP” to access your location?") { (alert) -> Bool in
            alert.buttons["Only While Using the App"].tap()

            return true
        }
```

The above code works for both if alert comes or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an interruption monitor is the correct way. However, it's safer to check if the alert being displayed is the alert you're expecting before you interact with the alert:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Allow “APP” to access your location?") { (alert) -> Bool in
    let button = alert.buttons["Only While Using the App"]
    if button.exists {
        button.tap()
        return true // The alert was handled
    }

    return false // The alert was not handled
}
```

Comment: It didn't work to me until I add app.tap() after this. Then it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    let app2 = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
    let button = app2.alerts.firstMatch.buttons["Allow While Using App"]
    button.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
    button.tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to allow user's location:

```
    // MARK: - Setup
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
            alert.buttons["Allow Once"].tap()
            return true
        }
    }
```

In this setup, I "register" the interruption monitor for tapping the allow button, so in this case I can dismiss that modal. Now, there's my test:

```
    // MARK: - Test change mall
    
    func testChangeMall() {
        let selectorChangeButton = app.buttons["change_mall_button"]
        XCTAssert(selectorChangeButton.exists, "Selector change button does not exist")
        selectorChangeButton.tap()
        app.navigationBars.firstMatch.tap()
        let cell = app.staticTexts["Shopping Centre"]
        XCTAssert(cell.exists, "There's no cell with this title")
        cell.tap()
        sleep(1)
        let label = app.staticTexts["Shopping Centre"]
        XCTAssert(label.exists, "Nothing changes")
    }
```

In this test, simply I go to a view controller with a list sorted by location. First, I need to dismiss the location's system alert. So, first I dismiss that modal and then I tap a cell from my TableView. Then, I need to show it in my main view controller so I dismiss my view controller and I expect the same title.

Happy Coding!